How do you represent quaternion rotations in 2 dimensions?
I'm developing in Android Studio Java with two Bluetooth IMUs that give quaternions. The sensors are oriented in the following way to start:

In the image shown, this is considered the “zero” position. NOTE: XYZ is displayed on the sensors. This position should be represented on the phone screen like this:

The green circle represents the angular difference between the two sensors. This circle moves based on the orientation of the sensors. The orange circle is meant to be a target and therefore the distance between the two circles is the distance from being in line as shown in the zero position.
With these sensors I’m only concerned with two rotations for each of them. The red sensor rotates about Y and Z, whereas the blue sensor rotates about X and Y. Both of these sensors can rotate about the third axis, but I’m just not really concerned with it. If it’s absolutely necessary, these rotations could be represented by the black notch shown in the image above.
My question is how do I take the quaternions given by the sensors and represent them in 2 dimensions? So for example, a rotation like:

would be represented:

What I've tried: With the assistance of ChatGPT (since I’m somewhat new to quaternions still), I got this method, which moved the blue circle above the orange in it's zero. I’m not really sure of where CGPT got these conversions, but it’s what I have so far.
private PointF quaternionTo2D(Quaternion q) { 
   float angleX = (float) Math.atan2(2.0f * (q.w() * q.x() + q.y() * q.z()), 1.0f - 2.0f * (q.x() * q.x() + q.y() * q.y())); 
   float angleY = (float) Math.asin(2.0f * (q.w() * q.y() - q.z() * q.x())); // Mapping angles to screen coordinates 
   float x = (float) Math.sin(angleX); float y = (float) Math.sin(angleY); 
   Log.i("QuaternionTo2D", "Quaternion: " + q + " -> PointF: x=" + x + ", y=" + y); 
   return new PointF(x, y); 
}

I'm feeding this method the relative rotation quaternion calculated by multiplying the conjugate of the red sensors quaternion by the blue sensors quaternion.
Any recommendations/tips are appreciated! I can also clarify any further details.

This is too much for one SO question. Please focus on one specific programming problem. Maybe you are lucky and someone is so kind and invests the time to work through this (for free) but that's not really the purpose of SO. Good luck.

I appreciate the feedback (being new to StackOverflow). I'm trying to be very specific to my problem by including a lot of information on my project itself, because I have noticed in a lot of other posts I've seen people complain of not having enough detail. If no one wants to take the time to read it, then so be it. I personally think that this scenario poses an interesting question that I haven't seen elsewhere so I felt I should include some context as to why I'm asking it.

Don't worry, providing details is very good. Context is also good, as long as it doesn't distract from the actual problem. I'm refering to time including time to solve the problem. It's not just about reading the question. One has to read and comprehend the problem, maybe refresh some theory, maybe write a little program for debugging, find the problem, implement a solution, write it in an appropriate answer ... That's work, not just giving a little help in a simple programming problem. Maybe I'm wrong and there is just one sign wrong or something. But one has to find it first. ;)

@JoeyWagner Actually deciding how much to context and details to include is actually a pretty hard decision, but also a great skill to have - especially as a researcher! When asking a question on StackOverflow, both extremes tend to be bad: not enough details and we couldn't help you, but too much detail and it becomes daunting to try to help. I recommend reading [mre] which gives some great advice on how to find the best balance.

Also, a personal recommendation: if you're plotting a figure with circles and vectors and angles and other things, one diagram is worth a thousand words ;-)

@Stef I appreciate the further advice. I'll be working on an edit to the post that will hopefully make things more concise... and include a diagram :)

I'd like to add that IMUs like these quickly cummulate an error.

@akuzminykh most definitely. Fortunately for the duration that we need to use these each time, they seem to avoid drift as long as we keep calibrating them every 2-3 runs.

We need to know more about the coordinate system for the quaternions. But assuming a typical i is the x-axis, j is the y-axis and k is the z-axis, you can figure out which rotation each axis represents from the right hand rule. Namely that i is the y-z rotation, j is the z-x rotation, and k is the x-y rotation.
From what you've said, you want the k coordinate for the blue sensor and the i coordinate for the red sensor. This gives you your two numbers, and then it is up to you to display them in your UI.

After discussion in the comments, I have a guess about what the sensor means. This is something that should be tested by playing around with small, controlled, angles.
The identity is W=1. The X, Y, and Z components give you the axis around which it rotated. sin(θ) = sqrt(X^2 + Y^2 + Z^2). The angle that you want is asin(X / sqrt(W^2 + X^2). Replace X with whatever coordinate that you're interested in.
You'll have to play around to figure out how to handle the intended difference in orientation between the red and blue sensors. My guess is that if u is the starting orientation of red, and v is the actual orientation, you want to look at u^(-1) v. Where u^(-1) = (u_w - i*u_x - j*u_y - k*u_z)/(u_w^2 + u_x^2 + u_y^2 + y_z^2). Note that multiplication is noncommutative, so the order matters. But that's only a best guess - you may find that something different works better.

First off, I appreciate the response. You are correct in your assumptions about the coordinate system, but I'm still a little confused and I think (if you’re willing) it would be helpful if you could tell me mathematically what to do or point out the changes in some example quaternions. In zero position, the blue sensor read W=-0.417 X=0.569 Y=0.438 Z=0.557 and the red sensor read W=0.055 X=-0.001 Y=0.001 Z=0.998. Then when oriented in the same way as the picture above, the blue sensor stayed the same and red read W=-0.271 X=0.082 Y=0.026 Z=0.959. These are relatively normalized to 3 decimals.

With what you’re saying, (and correct me if I’m wrong) I should be focused on the changes in the component that I’m not using. In this case only the red sensor is changing so I should use the change in X value from those quaternions? But how do I recognize the change in Y and Z from this one value? I feel like I’m still missing something.

@JoeyWagner Do you have documentation for the sensor? I'm just making a statement about how using the imaginary part of the quaternion translates into a physical rotation. But I don't know where the W in your sensor comes from. It looks like https://www.wit-motion.com/proztsz/43.html is your sensor, but I don't have documentation on it either. I think you need some work before you can say that you have a quaternion, or what your quaternion actually means.

Just to give a trivial example, is the sensor telling you its position relative to the rest of the world, or the rest of the world's position relative to it?

Yeah, that's the sensor, and you're absolutely correct about the documentation. It's been a bit challenging figuring things out because the company isn't super transparent. From my experience, the sensor appears to be providing its orientation relative to the rest of the world. I’ve come to this conclusion because each time the sensors are calibrated, the identity quaternion always results in a similar orientation. I’ve tested this by calibrating it in various ways and orientations (I can go more in depth on calibration if necessary but at the moment that doesn’t seem necessary).

Also I find the last statement you made before that question interesting. Are you saying that I can’t assume that the data given in their app as Q0 Q1 Q2 and Q3 is not quaternion data correlating to W X Y and Z? Because the data certainly seems to act in this way. And if it is a quaternion, it might function differently than quaternion data from other sensors?

@JoeyWagner I took a guess at what it is doing, and added that to my answer. Please play with it and decide if you think that it makes sense given what you are seeing.
